# Regex to replace string with quotes

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace quotes in following string.

```
String str = "This is 'test()ing' and test()ing'";
```

Final output should be "This is test()ing and test()ing'";

i.e replace only if it starts with 'test() and ends with '. Text in between remains the same.

This one is not working.

```
str = str.replaceAll("^('test())(.*)(')$", "test()$2");
```

Please suggest suitable regex for the same.

Comment: It's not working because `(.*)` is greedy; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regular expression will have the desired outcome:

```
    str = str.replaceAll("'test\\(\\)(.*?)'", "test()$1");
```

with `.*?` the string is matched lazily and doesn't match to the end of the whole string.

Comment: that's what is required.. thx.. matching lazily will ensure it stops at first closing quote(')..

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you actually want to have the `^` and `$` anchors (start/end of line) in your regex.

Aside from that, it will consume more than you want.  If you want the `.*` to stop at the *earliest point* it can continue, you should make it match reluctantly, like `.*?`.

So your regex would be:

```
('test\(\))(.*?)(')
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that unless you need to capture each of the three groups, you can greatly simplify the regex by using `'test\(\).*?'` to match. Of course, this does no good if you need to capture anything.

Comment: Yeah, occurred to me to mention that, but you know, poor little parens, they're not hurting anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("'(test\\(\\)[^']*)'", "$1");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nK0tW1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Make the middle part non greedy:

```
(')(.*?)(')
```

i.e.

```
str = str.replaceAll("(')(.*?)(')", "$2");
```

and if it should always start with `test()`, add

```
str = str.replaceAll("(')(test().*?)(')", "$2");
```

Check this [example](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRi7segSDA/index.html) and this [one](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRi7segSDA/index.html).